# How do I get my ember.js app to import modules installed from bower or npm

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ecmascript-6, es6-module-loader

I'm pretty new to some of this stuff and I feel like I must just be missing something simple. I have a very basic Ember.js app that I created with the CLI tool flowing the guide. The code is at https://github.com/nfriedly/particle-webhook-manager

It has a couple of routes and components, and a single third-party dependency, particle-api-js. I installed it twice, via bower and npm, and I'm importing it in one of my components [like so](https://github.com/nfriedly/particle-webhook-manager/blob/master/app/components/login-form.js#L2):

```
import particle from 'particle-api-js';
```

I start up my server with `ember serve` and it builds successfully. I then open my browser to http://localhost:4200/login where I load the component and it gives me the following error in my console:

```
Error: Could not find module `particle-api-js` imported from `particle-webhook-manager/components/login-form`
```

So, my main question is: what am I doing wrong here/how do I make it work?

My secondary question is: why did it "build" successfully and then throw a runtime error for the missing module - shouldn't it have found that in the build stage?

Comment: I think you need to import that module in ember-cli-build.js like so (paths and name might be wrong): `app.import('bower_components/particle-webhook-manager/whateverthefileiscalled.js');`

Comment: since that module doesn't provide an eber-install that's the usual way I have to go with such stuff

Comment: Yep, that and then using the global `Particle` worked. Not quite what I was hoping for, but good enough for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use `bower` anymore. Use [ember browserify](https://github.com/ef4/ember-browserify) to import things installed with `npm`.

You can import `bower` modules in your `ember-cli-build.js` with `app.import('bower_components/...js')`.

You can not `import` them directly, but you can create a `vendor shim` to provide this for you. Checkout the `ember-cli` documentation for this.